# How to freeze a row in NodeJS when using console.log

Tags: node.js

For example, I am doing

```
console.log('Press A to Stop')
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++) console.log(i);
```

I want that the message *Press a To Stop*, will continue to appear all the time.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

[image]

The only solution I think about, is to calcuare number rows in the screen, and render frame after frame, (x-1 rows), and add the bottom row each time.

### More Info

I want to show logs on the screen. (queries, requests, errors, and more), and I want the user to be able to change the log level, I want to show the instruction on the screen while he seeing the logs.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `console` is the right interface to do that (but I might be wrong). You could try to use a simple web-based interface, that way you would have a lot more control over the positioning. Or there might be other libraries available that have more output formatting available.

Comment: web-based is make the app much open a port listen send requests...

Comment: What you need is REPL. https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html  Read Eval Print Loop.

Comment: RTL is interesting. How it can help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, but you can't use `console.log` (which isn't a biggie in your case).

What you will need to do is the following:

1. instead of `console.log` use `process.stdout.write(x)` where `x` is the output you want (followed by a new line character `\n`)
2. use `process.stdout.write("Press A to Stop");` (note there is no new line character at the end)
3. right before you need to write the next line of information use `process.stdout.clearLine();` which clears what's currently on the last line of the output
4. repeat steps 1 to 3

Comment: WOW!! I want to give you gold!